# checking name in list it is there than update client table else category and client table

Tags: java

I have List which has names. I am providing name by using Scanner by using advance for loop and checking if the name is in the list it will update the client table else it will update . Category and client table both are in database .The problem is if  my list has 4 names it should check if condition only and not go to the else statement till it check the 4 names , if name is not there than(which i give from scanner) should go to else condition needed a logic

```
String n = scann.nextLine();
  List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
  li.add("abc");
  li.add("def");
  li.add("ghi");
  li.add("jkl");
  for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
     if (n.equals(li.get(i))) {
       System.out.println("client table update");
     } else {
       System.out.println("category and client table update");
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda get the gist of what you are asking, but please be more precise.

From what i understand from your question is, you want to print either the first or the second thing, depending on wether your name is in the list or not. And in your case, both get printed.

That is because your prints are inside the for loop, thus printing 4 times and printing both options regardless, since your name cant be all 4 names at the same time.

Here is how i would solve this:

```
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("abc");
        li.add("def");
        li.add("ghi");
        li.add("jkl");
        boolean inList = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
            if (n.equals(li.get(i))) {
                inList = true;
            }
        }
        if (inList) {
            System.out.println("client table update");
        } else {
            System.out.println("category and client table update");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `contains()` to check whether the name exists in the list i.e.

```
if(li.contains(n)){
    System.out.println("client table update");
}
else{
    System.out.println("category and client table update");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String n = scann.nextLine();
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add("abc");
        li.add("def");
        li.add("ghi");
        li.add("jkl");

        for (String data : li) {
            if (li.contains(n)) {
                System.out.println("client table update");
            } else {
                System.out.println("category and client table update");
            }
        }
```

Comment: this would stil print both prints